# Получение значения из json

Tags: json, php

Есть вот такой json

```
[{"params":{"3141345555":"3293053"}}]
```

Как узнать, что за число на месте 3141345555

Comment: Преобразуйте объект к массиву и переберите ключи foreach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data = [{"params":{"3141345555":"3293053"}}];

for(key in data[0]['params']){
  alert(key)
}
```

Comment: Это же js....

Comment: ну так и массив js

Comment: Ну и в php можно разобрать json

Answer (score 0):

```
<? 
   print_r(json__decode('[{"params":{"3141345555":"3293053"}}]', 1)); 
?>
```

У меня получилось

Array[0]['params'][3141345555] = 3293053

Comment: Мне нужно получить ключ 3141345555

Comment: ну, надо просто немного решительности в дополнение к вышенаписанному ответу

    $data = json_decode('[{"params":{"3141345555":"3293053"}}]', true);
    $key = key($data['0']['params']);